# Maven: Package submodule and move jar to parent resources before install

Tags: java, maven

I hava a maven project with exactly one submodule. The jar which is generated from that submodule with mvn package is needed in the parent project to be started as an external java process. The parent project is a library and the packaging is of type pom.

I would like to achieve that calling mvn install on the parent project runs mvn package on the submodule first and then moves the generated jar to the resources folder of the parent project before it is installed to the local repository.

How must the pom of the parent be configured to achieve this behaviour?

I'm aware of the resources plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) but i want it to be executed between the package of the submodule and the install of the parent module.

Thx!

Comment: You do not need a multi module project if you have one module, just have the jar project.

Comment: Is used the parent project as second module. Maybe that's wrong usage. I have one module which produces a jar. This jar is needed in the second modules resources directory before installing it to the local repo. I now changed the structure to a 2-module project.

Comment: @mcheck that seems better, are their any issues now?

Comment: no, it all works now. should I delete the question?

Comment: @mcheck, leave the question it may be useful for someone else :)